# Revolution Slider Cross-browser display issues

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, cross-browser, revolution-slider

I have a situation trying to make a slide look the same in different browsers.
This [page](http://goo.gl/DkuFmq) was created in Chrome. Arranging the elements in a specific way, these are displayed correctly, but pretty altered in IE browser and/or Mozilla depending on content.

IE 11 asymmetrical elements position 
[image]

Chrome v.42 elements centered position 
[image]

I've read something about resetting/normalizing the `css` and I've tried to implement the `normalize.css` code into the `css` slider's custom field but the result is the same.
Any thoughts?